# How to write query for created User, Created date, Modified User, Modified date for a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help in knowing how to automatically make the table load the values for Created user , created date, modified user and modified date,

once any data goes into the table , we should have the Created user and created date column value to be fixed but the modified user and modified date should change

Comment: What table, loaded into where, using what language?  Do you have a table structure?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the default value of a column to `GetDate()` for the datetime columns and to `SYSTEM_USER` for the current user. This is good for the Creation of the records.

For the modification columns you need to add a trigger.

Also worth reading...

[How to use system_user in audit trigger but still use connection pooling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93848/how-to-use-system-user-in-audit-trigger-but-still-use-connection-pooling)

Answer (score 0):

Admiting your table structure looks like this -dont forget the DEFAULT GETDATE()- :

```
YourTable
---------
CreatedUser
CreatedDate  DEFAULT GETDATE()  
ModifierUser   
ModifierDate
```

On the insertion you trigger a function that will update ModifiedUser and ModifiedDate to GETDATE()

Answer (score 0):

For createdby and createtime you can use columns default values:

```
CreatedAt DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE(),
CreatedBy VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT USER
```

For UpdatedAt you have to create a trigger which sets the values:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [t_Table_upd] ON YourTable AFTER UPDATE AS 
set nocount on 
UPDATE YourTable
set 
    YourTable.[Modified] = getdate(), 
    YourTable.[ModifiedBy] = USER, 
    YourTable.[Version] = YourTable.[Version] + 1 
FROM
    DELETED d
WHERE
    YourTable.ID = d.ID
```

Comment: but if i am using sql authentication, how will it take the windows user name instead of sql authentication name

Comment: When you use sql authentification, the sql server can't guess who you are in terms of a windows user name.
When you connect using windows authentification, NAME will return the windows user name authenticated: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186738.aspx